# Raspberry Pi command not found, only printng out bytes

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

so i just installed Raspbian on my Pi and wanted to test some python scripts. However if i try to execute the script or even go into the Python IDE the shell freezes for some seconds and then prints out a massive amount of bytes and tells me command not found. Already checked if Python is installed. Also happened with commands like wget and curl.
Always looks something like this:

```
pi@xpi:~ $ wget
/usr/bin/wget: line 1: $'\377\315\314Ή\211\211\210\210\210\210 ......
\210\210\210\210\210\210\210\211\210\210\210\210\210\210\210': command not found
```

Comment: Did you edit some files manually? Which instruction did you follow?

Comment: Does this also happen if you log in as root? Not sure if you can do that.